# Randomly picking a value from multiple returns in JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, parsing

This is my code, it works fine for a single return of value, however, what if the results are multiple and I want to pick one randomly?

My code:

```
class CheckSummonerLevel
{
    public class GetVariable
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string secondid { get; set; }
    }
    public static string Get(string url)
    {
        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string json= client.DownloadString(url);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetVariable>(json);
        string secondid = result.secondid;
        return result.id;
    }
}
```

This returns a single value, however, what if my JSON is this:

```
{
"Values": [
    {
    "id": 123456
    },
    {
    "id": 987654
    },
    {
    "id": 654987
    },
    {
    "id": 333222
    }
],
"secondid": 88888
}
```

And I want to randomly pick a value from "id" fields?

Something like:

```
Random a = new Random();
int r = a.Next(1,4);
return result.ElementAt(r).id;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could modify the structure of `GetVariable` to match the Json, like the following code :

1 - Class structure :

```
public class GetVariable
{
    public GetId[] Values { get; set; }
    public string secondid { get; set; }
}

public class GetId
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

2 - Deserialization of the *Json* and get one value Randomly :

```
GetVariable result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetVariable>(json);

GetId[] values = result.Values;
string secondId = result.secondid;

int r = new Random().Next(0, values.Length);
int res = values.ElementAt(r).id;

Console.WriteLine(res + " ", secondId);
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: You should use `Values.Length` as the second parameter of the `Next` call instead of hardcoding it to `3`.

Comment: @BrianRogers you're right, updated by `Length -1` thank you.

Comment: You should use `Length`, not `Length - 1`, since the maxValue argument to [`Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is *ex*clusive.

Comment: @RufusL that's true, *The Next(Int32, Int32) overload returns random integers that range from minValue to maxValue - 1*, updated. thank you.

Comment: Please don't do `new Random().Next`. This is prone to causing duplicate values if called in a loop. You should only ever create one instance of `Random` per thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity no loop here.

Comment: @Sajid - Yes, I can see that. That's why I said "if". It's just best to program defensively and learn good habits.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah that's it, thanks :). i don't know why is downvoted.

Comment: @Sajid - Because of the `new Random().Next(...)`. Trust me, if that was done properly you'd get an upvote.